# Apache VirtualHost Loading the Wrong Page

Tags: apache, fonts, virtualhost

## Problems

An Apache VirtualHost keeps loading the wrong directory when I'm telling it to load a completely different part.  Here is what I have for the VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Workspace/Font"
    ServerName fonts.wrks.tk
#   ErrorLog "/Logs/Workarea/Fonts/Error.log"
#   CustomLog "/Logs/Workarea/Fonts/Access.log" common
    <Directory "/Workspace/Font">
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So, the problem, I'm telling it to load `/Workspace/Font` But it's not, it's loading `/Workspace` instead.  I'm not sure how this came to be.

---

## Attempt at Solution

There's not much I could do considering that the search on Google gave me no relevant results on what I was trying to fix.  But regardless, here is some things I did myself to try and fix it.

- Restarted Apache Multiple times
- Changed permissions around:

  - `sudo chown -R daemon:daemon /Workspace/Fonts` (I run XAMPP, and the user and group is `daemon`)
- Checked Error Logs (Nothing Relevant to the problem was printed)
- Created a index folder and/or tried to access folder and files within the domain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache VirtualHost not working correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474141/apache-virtualhost-not-working-correctly)

Comment: Not a duplicate, different question.  That question I asked was about the domain.  This is about a path to a file.

Comment: And since this is a server configuration problem it's off topic anyway. Ask on [sf] or [su]

Comment: Did you verify that the access log look as it should? Meaning the client really ask for `/Workspace/Font`. Is this the only VirtualHost? I guess there are no `.htaccess` files present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I didn't have the VirtualHosts line uncommented, thanks for anyone that helped in the past.  But everything works now.